# ant design: modify border-radius for Input component

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-css-modules

I have the following ant design search input component:

```
 <Search
  size="large"
  placeholder="Search..."
  className="dashboardSearch"
  />
```

I am trying to modify the border radius to give it a circular shape but everything i try in my css file doesnt work.

css file:

```
.dashboardSearch {
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;

}

.ant-input-search {
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

is there anyway to modify the border radius of the search input component? usually when I modify the ant design class name directly it works. but in this case it doesn't. Is there another way that I am missing?

Comment: Hi , I am stuck with the same problem, Any Idea on how to do this for the Input text field?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to target `.antd-input` class inside the `Input.Search`.

For example with `CSS-in-JS`:

```js
const RoundSearch = styled(Input.Search)`
  .ant-input {
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <RoundSearch />
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

Or in your case:

```
.dashboardSearch {
  .ant-input {
    border-radius: 25px;
  }
}
```

[image: Edit Q-57343486-StyleInputSearch]